# Add order details Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm using the following gem to connect to Microsoft Dynamics CRM: https://github.com/TinderBox/dynamics_crm. I was able to connect and add contacts, leads and a few other things just fine. My problem is, I can't figure out how to add an order and order details. Here is the code I am using to create an order detail:

```
details = Hash.new
    details = {
        'quantity' => 1000.0,
        'productid' => product,
        'salesorderid' => DynamicsCRM::XML::EntityReference.new("salesorder", order.id),
        'uomid' => DynamicsCRM::XML::EntityReference.new("uom", 'F5AE673D-5D8E-E211-8AD0-78E3B5101E8F'),
        'createdon' => Time.now.getutc,
        'salesorderstatecode' => 1,
        'description' => 'This is just a test order',
    }
    orderDetail = client.create('salesorderdetail', details)
```

This runs fine, but when I check in the CRM backend, there is no record under Order Details. I also can't figure out how to send custom fields, I have tried 'new_shirtsize' => 'XL', but I just get an error that the field 'new_shirtsize' doesn't exist for the entity 'salesorderdetail'.

Comment: in JavaScript we do it like
details.salesorderid = { Id: order.id, LogicalName: 'salesorder' };

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess, but I had a look in the [specs](https://github.com/TinderBox/dynamics_crm/blob/6eaae4a58a0c59fd5f2328da45ed54db05e80969/spec/lib/xml/attributes_spec.rb#L12) of the gem you mentioned. Looks like the two parameters need to be written like so:

```
details = {}
details['salesorderid'] = {}
details['salesorderid']['Id'] = order.id
details['salesorderid']['LogicalName'] = 'salesorder'
client.create('orderdetail', details)
```

Btw, you can make this a little more compact:

```
client.create('orderdetail', salesorderid: 
  {'Id' => order.id, 'LogicalName' => 'salesorder'} )
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things to try:

1. Remove this line:

`details['salesorderid']['Id'] = order.id`

**Reason:** When creating a new record via `CRM API` you don't have to provide the `Id`. `CRM` will generate this for you. This is the recommended approach when creating a new `CRM` record, rather than specifying the `Id`.

2. Check that `order.id` is `NOT NULL`. I suspect the object is `NULL`.

**Reason:** When creating a new record via `CRM API` you *can* (if you really want to) provide the `Id`, but you have to check it has a valid `GUID` in the form of (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx), `where x = is of HEX value`.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out that there is a function to generate a Guid, and I was able to successfully generate it by using `'salesorderid' => DynamicsCRM::XML::EntityReference.new("salesorder", order.id)`. The function ran without an error, and it even returned a Guid of the recently created sales order details. But when I check in the CRM backend, there is no sales order details record. Any idea why this might be happening? I updated my original post with my new code.

Comment: To look for the record in CRM, try using advanced find to search for Order Details and remove all filters. To send custom fields and if you are calling the rest endpoint of the CRM API, the field names are case sensitive. I'm guessing your field name should be 'new_ShirtSize'.